# Compare two columns from two dataframes and delete rows in one if values are equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes:

```
df1:

  ... id  ...
0     123
1     231
2     321

df2:

  ... id  ...
4     122
13    231
75    323
```

I need to loop over `id` column in `df2` and if value from that column exists in `df1['id']` this row should be deleted from `df1`. So I get:

```
  ... id  ...
0     123
2     321

df2:

  ... id  ...
4     122
13    231
75    323
```

Dataframes shapes are different so I can't concat them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `isin`

```
out = df1[~df1['id'].isin(df2['id'])]
```